# send parameter in soap web service from ios

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

i am using SOAP services to get the data from the servrer to my ios app. now i need to upload some data from the app to server.how can i do it from the SOAP message. here is my SOAP service.

```
POST /NoteService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ios.myurl.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.myurl.com/CreateNoteUsingXMl"   

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateNoteUsingXMl xmlns="http://www.myurl.com">
  <AccountID>string</AccountID>
  <Username>string</Username>
  <Mypass>string</Mypass>
  <NoteXML>string</NoteXML>
  <isSign>int</isSign>
  <noteID>long</noteID>
</CreateNoteUsingXMl>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i pass accountid,username etc. parameter in POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy create an NSString

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<CreateNoteUsingXMl xmlns="http://www.myurl.com">\n"
                          " <Username>%@</Username>\n"
                          "<Mypass>%@</Mypass>\n"
                          "<NoteXML>%@</NoteXML>\n"
                         "</CreateNoteUsingXMl>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                         ,username
                         , mypassword
                         , notexml
                         ];
```

Now create `NSURL`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"What Ever"];
```

Create `NSMutableURLRequest`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];


[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

Do rest of things you want ...