# Use Sabre SOAP API with iOS

Tags: ios, sabre

Does anyone know how to use sabre SOAP web services with IOS? anyone has done that ? I am using **AFNetworking** for the network call.

I am using AFHTTPRequestOperation to make a call to web service but that web service require authentication.

Authentication parameters are `username` , `password` , and `IPCC`. I can set username and password by

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"aaaaa" password:@"aaaaaa" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone]; 
[operation setCredential:credential];
```

but how can set that IPCC parameter?

Comment: Its a webservice  call;  its platform independent.   Post what you have tried/or what isn't working...

Comment: I am using AFHTTPRequestOperation to make a call to web service but that web service require authentication. Authentication parameters are "username" , "password" , and "IPCC".
i can set username and password by
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"aaaaa" password:@"aaaaaa" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

 [operation setCredential:credential];

but how can set that IPCC parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like (quick and dirty):

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                      "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:eb=\"http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\">"
                    "    <SOAP-ENV:Header>"
                    "        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand=\"1\" eb:version=\"1.0\">"
                    "            <eb:ConversationId/>"
                    "            <eb:From>"
                    "                <eb:PartyId type=\"urn:x12.org:IO5:01\">999999</eb:PartyId>"
                    "            </eb:From>"
                    "            <eb:To>"
                    "                <eb:PartyId type=\"urn:x12.org:IO5:01\">123123</eb:PartyId>"
                    "            </eb:To>"
                    "            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>"
                    "            <eb:Service eb:type=\"OTA\">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>"
                    "            <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>"
                    "            <eb:MessageData>"
                    "                <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>"
                    "                <eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:Timestamp>"
                    "                <eb:TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</eb:TimeToLive>"
                    "            </eb:MessageData>"
                    "        </eb:MessageHeader>"
                    "        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility\">"
                    "            <wsse:UsernameToken>"
                    "                <wsse:Username>%@</wsse:Username>"
                    "                <wsse:Password>%@</wsse:Password>"
                    "                <Organization>%@</Organization>"
                    "                <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>"
                    "            </wsse:UsernameToken>"
                    "        </wsse:Security>"
                    "    </SOAP-ENV:Header>"
                    "    <SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                    "        <eb:Manifest SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand=\"1\" eb:version=\"1.0\">"
                    "            <eb:Reference xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xlink:href=\"cid:rootelement\" xlink:type=\"simple\"/>"
                    "        </eb:Manifest>"
                    "    </SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                    "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"      
                     ,username
                     ,password
                     ,ipccValue

                     ];
```

I assume you mean the ipccValue in the Organization block, rather than the eb:CPAId block

from https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/Authentication
and credits to [send parameter in soap web service from ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379547/send-parameter-in-soap-web-service-from-ios)

Comment: I already tried this call goes successful but its returning me strange xml which is not true. its quite similar to WSDL file's content.

Comment: The CPAId must match the Organization.  Does it?

Comment: yes its must...... Thank you for your response but now  i am not using this SOAP we moved to rest API's.

Answer (score 0):

When i tried the above snippet its returning me this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" xmlns:tns="https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" targetNamespace="https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" schemaLocation="SessionCreateRQRS.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" schemaLocation="msg-header-2_0.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" schemaLocation="wsse.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="GetSessionCreateInput">
        <part name="header" element="eb:MessageHeader"/>
        <part name="header2" element="wsse:Security"/>
        <part name="body" element="xsd1:SessionCreateRQ"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSessionCreateOutput">
        <part name="header" element="eb:MessageHeader"/>
        <part name="header2" element="wsse:Security"/>
        <part name="body" element="xsd1:SessionCreateRS"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SessionCreatePortType">
        <operation name="SessionCreateRQ">
            <input message="tns:GetSessionCreateInput"/>
            <output message="tns:GetSessionCreateOutput"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SessionCreateSoapBinding" type="tns:SessionCreatePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="SessionCreateRQ">
            <soap:operation soapAction="OTA"/>
            <input>
                <soap:header message="tns:GetSessionCreateInput" part="header" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:GetSessionCreateInput" part="header2" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:header message="tns:GetSessionCreateOutput" part="header" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:GetSessionCreateOutput" part="header2" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SessionCreateRQService">
        <port name="SessionCreatePortType" binding="tns:SessionCreateSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://webservices.sabre.com"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: this is the response i am receiving